# Slow download with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, html, download

I'm trying to make a method that download a webpage.
First, i create a HttpURLConnection.
Second, i call the connect() method.
Third, i read the data through a BufferedReader.

The problem is that with some pages i get reasonable reading times, but with some pages it's Very slow (it can take about 10 minutes!). The slow pages are always the same, and they comes from the same website. Opening those pages with the browser takes just a few seconds instead of 10 minutes. Here is the code

```
static private String getWebPage(PageNode pagenode)
{
    String result;
    String inputLine;
    URI url;
    int cicliLettura=0;
    long startTime=0, endTime, openConnTime=0,connTime=0, readTime=0;
    try
    {
        if(Core.logGetWebPage())
            startTime=System.nanoTime();
        result="";
        url=pagenode.getUri();
        if(Core.logGetWebPage())
            openConnTime=System.nanoTime();
        HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) url.toURL().openConnection();
        if(url.toURL().getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https"))
            yc=(HttpsURLConnection)yc;
        yc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"); 
        yc.connect();
        if(Core.logGetWebPage())
            connTime=System.nanoTime();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            result=result+inputLine+"\n";
            cicliLettura++;
        }
        if(Core.logGetWebPage())
            readTime=System.nanoTime();
        in.close();
        yc.disconnect();
        if(Core.logGetWebPage())
        {
            endTime=System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(/*result+*/"getWebPage eseguito in "+(endTime-startTime)/1000000+" ms. Size: "+result.length()+" Response Code="+yc.getResponseCode()+" Protocollo="+url.toURL().getProtocol()+" openConnTime: "+(openConnTime-startTime)/1000000+" connTime:"+(connTime-openConnTime)/1000000+" readTime:"+(readTime-connTime)/1000000+" cicliLettura="+cicliLettura);
        }
        return result;
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Eccezione: "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();  
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here you have two log samples
One of the "normal" pages
getWebPage executed Size: 48261 Response Code=200 Protocol=http openConnTime: 0 connTime:1 readTime:569 cicliLettura=359

One of the "slow" pages http://ricette.giallozafferano.it/Pan-di-spagna-al-cacao.html/allcomments
looks like this
getWebPage executed Size: 1748261 Response Code=200 Protocol=http openConnTime: 0 connTime:1 readTime:596834 cicliLettura=35685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're likely seeing here is a result of the way you are collating `result`. Remember that `String`s in Java are immutable - therefore when string concatenation occurs, a new `String` has to be instantiated, which can often involve copying all the data contained in that `String`. You have the following code executing for every line:

```
result=result+inputLine+"\n";
```

Under the covers, this line involves:

1. A new StringBuffer is created with the entire content of `result` so far
2. `inputLine` is appended to the `StringBuffer`
3. The `StringBuffer` is converted to a `String`
4. A new `StringBuffer` is created for that `String`
5. A newline character is appended to that `StringBuffer`
6. The `StringBuffer` is converted to a `String`
7. That `String` is stored as `result`.

This operation will become more and more time-consuming as `result` gets bigger and bigger - and your results appear to show (albeit from a sample of 2!) that the results increase drastically with page size.

Instead, use `StringBuffer` directly.

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    buffer.append(inputLine).append('\n');
    cicliLettura++;
}
String result = buffer.toString();
```

Comment: Simply Great, very pro answer. Can you please send an explaining doc for that? That's the new output for that page: getWebPage Size: 1709466 Response Code=200 Protocollo=http openConnTime: 0 connTime:0 readTime:2257 cicliLettura=35686